# jquery tabs - save tab content on navigation within tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-ui-tabs

I have a webpage that uses the jquery tabs control.  In this page the tabs are dynamically generated based on what the user selects.  These tabs show the contents of pages in my web app.  For example the user chooses the category "Inventory" and then selects the option "Items" and it loads the "Inventory -> Items" web page in a new tab.  In the "Items" page there are links that can be clicked by the user which will navigate the tab to a different webpage in my web app (ex: Edit Item).  If the user clicks on a different tab (say the "Orders" tab) and then back to his "Items" tab it refreshes the tab to the page that the tab loads when it is newly created instead of the last place the user was when he left the tab.

How can I preserve the place where the user was when he left the tab, say editing an item?

I am using MVC 4 Razor and jquery.

For more clarity please see my complete html below:

```js
<script>
    debugger;
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var tabTemplate = "<li><a href='#{href}'>#{label}</a> <span class='ui-icon ui-icon-close' role='presentation'>Remove Tab</span></li>",
            tabCounter = 2;

        var tabs = $("#tabs").tabs();

        $("#open_module").button().on("click", function () {
            $("#dialog").dialog("open");
        });

        // Modal dialog init: custom buttons and a "close" callback resetting the form inside
        $("#dialog").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                Add: function () {
                    addTab();
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                },
                Cancel: function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            },
            close: function () {
                form[0].reset();
            }
        });

        // AddTab form: calls addTab function on submit and closes the dialog
        var form = $("#dialog").find("form").on("submit", function (event) {
            addTab();
            $("#dialog").dialog("close");
            event.preventDefault();
        });

        // Actual addTab function: adds new tab using the input from the form above
        function addTab() {
            var e = document.getElementById("page-links");
            var link = e[e.selectedIndex].value;
            var tabTitle = e[e.selectedIndex].text;
            var tabContent = "<object type='text/html' data='" + link + "' width='800px' height='600px' style='overflow:hidden;'/>";
            var label = tabTitle || "Tab " + tabCounter, id = "tabs-" + tabCounter, li = $(tabTemplate.replace(/#\{href\}/g, "#" + id).replace(/#\{label\}/g, label)), tabContentHtml = tabContent || "Tab " + tabCounter + " content.";

            tabs.find(".ui-tabs-nav").append(li);
            tabs.append("<div id='" + id + "'>" + tabContentHtml + "</div>");
            tabs.tabs("refresh");
            tabCounter++;
        }

        // Close icon: removing the tab on click
        tabs.on("click", "span.ui-icon-close", function () {
            var panelId = $(this).closest("li").remove().attr("aria-controls");
            $("#" + panelId).remove();
            tabs.tabs("refresh");
        });

        tabs.on("keyup", function (event) {
            if (event.altKey && event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.BACKSPACE) {
                var panelId = tabs.find(".ui-tabs-active").remove().attr("aria-controls");
                $("#" + panelId).remove();
                tabs.tabs("refresh");
            }
        });

        
    });

    function LoadLinks(category) {
        var url = "/Home/LoadLinks/";
        var e = document.getElementById("categories");
        var _custid = e[e.selectedIndex].value;
        $("#page-links").empty();

        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            data: { cat: category },
            cache: false,
            type: "POST",
            success: function (data) {
                $.each(data, function (i, data) {
                    $("#page-links").append('<option value="' + data.Value + '">' + data.Text + '</option>');
                });
            },
            error: function (reponse) {
                alert("error : " + reponse);
            }
        });
        return false;
    }

</script>
```

```html
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "my title";
}
@section featured {
    <section class="featured">
        <div class="content-wrapper">
            <hgroup class="title">
                <h1>@ViewBag.Title.</h1>
                <h2>@ViewBag.Message</h2>
            </hgroup>
            <p>
                
            </p>
        </div>
    </section>
}
<button id="open_module">Open Module</button>

<div id="dialog" title="Open Module">
  <form>
    <fieldset class="ui-helper-reset">
        <legend>PageSelector</legend>
        <label id="category-label">Category</label>
        <select id="categories" onchange="javascript:LoadLinks(this.value);">
            <option value="0">Select one...</option>
            <option value="Inventory">Inventory</option>
            <option value="CustomerManagement">Customer Management</option>
            <option value="VendorManagement">Vendor Management</option>
            <option value="Invoicing">Invoicing</option>
            <option value="Receiving">Receiving</option>
            <option value="Purchasing">Purchasing</option>
            <option value="Human Resources">Human Resources</option>
            <option value="OrderEntry">Order Entry</option>
        </select>
        <select id="page-links">
            <option value="value">Select a category...</option>
        </select>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</div>

<div id="tabs">

    <ul>
        <li class="current"><a href="#tabs-1">About</a></li>
    </ul>

        <div id="tabs-1">
            <object type="text/html" data="/Home/About" width="800px" height="600px" style="overflow:hidden;"/>
        </div>

</div>
```

Comment: You can use cookies or localStorage to preserve a state. So every time a visitor clicks on different tabs just save the action in localStorage, then on a new page load chceck if you have any state saved - if yes load that state

Comment: Also, just came to my mind you can use # to save current state! That will work better with browser history and back button

Comment: Can you give an example?  I know how to save the tab list on page load but what I'm talking about is the content inside the tabs.  I hope what I am asking makes sense.

Comment: Ok, wow!  Just Another knock against Chrome :(

It works as expected in IE (browser I hate) and FireFox!  Looks like I am making this browser specific now...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the answer is, Chrome is the problem.  The site works as expected when opened from IE and FireFox, just Chrome wont play nice. And it's a shame, chrome was my favorite :(

For some reason Chrome reloads the Tab when you click on it, resulting in the default page being opened.  When you use IE or FireFox it doesn't reload the Tab on click.  So now I know why some websites are browser specific :)